# How to enforce a minimum version for dependencies in project.assets.json in ASP.NET project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dependencies, csproj

In my `project.csproj` file I have the following:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web" Version="5.0.1" />
```

However, my other dependencies pull in a lower version of the package as their dependencies. For example in my `project.assets.json` I see (18 total instances that pull version 4.5.0):

```
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/2.2.0": {
    "type": "package",
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features": "2.2.0",
      "System.Text.Encodings.Web": "4.5.0" // <-- the problem
    },
```

How can I enforce a minimum version for these dependencies? To be more specific, any version above 4.5.1 would work to fulfill my needs for compliance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that if you add the ProjectReference, that might actually solve the problem. Here is a good read:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution

After adding the ProjectReference, the `project.assets.json` still had the 4.5.0 as dependency but it only pulled in the ProjectReference version, which was 5.0.1 in this case.